# How to set a value in input automatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm using a hook that fills in my inputs automatically, according to the zip code the user enters. Then the user's address, street, etc are filled in automatically.

However, for the input to be filled in automatically, the component is re-rendering.

As my form is a modal it opens and closes again because of rendering. I need to make the user fill in the zip code, the inputs are filled in real time.

Can you help me with this?

**useCEP Hook:**

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import { api } from 'services/apiClient'

interface Cep {
  bairro: string
  logradouro: string
  localidade: string
  uf: string
}

export function useCep() {
  const [checkCep, setCheckCep] = useState<Cep>()

  const getCEP = async (e) => {
    const cep = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '')

    try {
      const { data } = await api.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`)

      setCheckCep(data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  return { checkCep, getCEP }
}
```

**Component:**

```
 const { control, formState, register, reset } = useFormContext()

 const { checkCep, getCEP } = useCep()

 useEffect(() => {
    reset({
      responsible: [
        {
          address: checkCep?.logradouro,
          district: checkCep?.bairro,
          city: checkCep?.localidade,
          state: checkCep?.uf,
          name: '',
          email: '',
          student_name: [],
          cep: '',
          residence: '',
          telephone: '',
          sex: ''
        }
      ]
    })
  }, [checkCep])

   <Input
     name="cep"
     type="number"
     label="Cep"
     {...register(`responsible.${index}.cep`)}
     error={errors?.responsible?.[index]?.cep}
     onBlur={(e) => getCEP(e)}
    />
    
   {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the `setValue` method instead of `reset` as it will reset the form.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue

Comment: I can't do that, because I'm using useFieldArray. Using setValue, I would have to pass the index to work, example: setValue(`responsible.${index}.address`, data.logradouro). But the index is on the map, so I have no way of reusing it.